# code crashes when using auto loop

Tags: c++, c++11

I am sorting a vector using a swap function.
When I use the loop:

`for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)`

code runs fine but when I use:
`for (auto const  &i:vec)`

it crashes!

`Error in ./run': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000001df0c20`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

template <class T>
void myswap(T &a,
            T &b)
{
    T temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}


int main() {

    const int N = 5;
    std::vector<int> vec = {112,32,11,4,7};

    std::cout << "\nInit\n";
    for (const auto &i:vec)
    {
        std::cout << i << "\t";
    }


    int j;
    for (auto const  &i:vec)
    //for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        j = i;
        while (j > 0 && vec[j] < vec[j-1]) 
        {
            myswap(vec[j], vec[j-1]);
            j--;
        }
    }


    std::cout << "\n\nFinal\n";
    for (const auto &i:vec)
    {
        std::cout << i << "\t";
    }

    std::cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are using `j` as an index into `vec`, but you are assigning it to a *value* from `vec`.  i.e. `j` will be `112` during the first iteration.  `j[112]` is then out of bounds.

Comment: seems like you misunderstood how the ranged based loop works. In `for (auto const &i : vec)`  the `i` is an element not an index (more precicelse a const reference to an element)

Comment: because `i` goes from being a loop index to the actual vector element... (which you assign to `j` and you use that as an index)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer already in the comments to the question (range based loop iterates over the *values*, **not** the *indices*), but for illustration, try this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v;
int j;
for(auto const& i : v)
{
    j = v;
}
```

You will quickly discover that this piece of code does not compile – a good compiler will show you an error like this one (from GCC):

> error: cannot convert 'std::vector<std::vector<int> >' to 'int' in assignment

What you now *could* do would be the following:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v;
for(auto const& i : v)
{
    std::vector<int> const& vv = v; // assign a reference
    std::vector<int> vvv = v;       // make a COPY(!)
}
```

Pretty self-explaining, isn't it?

Comment: Ok, thanks.I totally forgot (new  C++11 user) that `i` is an element when I use auto..

Answer (score 0):

it may be due to `auto const` try like this `const auto` and also you are using j in while loop instead of `i` you change it to j in while or change `for(const auto &j:vec)`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

template <class T>
void myswap(T &a,
            T &b)
{
    T temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}


int main() {

    const int N = 5;
    std::vector<int> vec = {112,32,11,4,7};

    std::cout << "\nInit\n";
    for (const auto &i:vec)
    {
        std::cout << i << "\t";
    }


    int j;
    for (const auto &j:vec)
    //for (int j = 0; j < vec.size(); j++)
    {

        while (j > 0 && vec[j] < vec[j-1]) 
        {
            myswap(vec[j], vec[j-1]);
            j--;
        }
    }


    std::cout << "\n\nFinal\n";
    for (const auto &i:vec)
    {
        std::cout << i << "\t";
    }

    std::cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the way you use `swap`, it is intended for `j` to represent a valid index of `vec`. Now `i` is not an index, but it is a value instead. When you assign `j=i`, then `j` contains `112` which is clearly out of bounds.

The way ranged loop works is that `i` takes the value `vec[0], vec[1], vec[2] ...` at each iteration.

[Read here to learn about ranged loop.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)